# Very low performance in the Witcher 2

Tags: the-witcher-2, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How firm are The Witcher 2's minimum required specs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22396/how-firm-are-the-witcher-2s-minimum-required-specs)

I went out and bought The Witcher 2 yesterday. But unfortunately it seems not matter how low I put the graphics settings it still runs horribly, it skips around and the video cant even keep up with the sound.

My Comp is as follows:

Windows 7 64-bit
   AMD Phenom II x6 1055t (6 CPUs) ~2.8GHz
   6GB Ram (2 1GBs @ 1333 and 2 2GBs @ 1333)

ATI Radeon HD 5450 with 1 GB dedicated and 3 GB total

My settings for the game were set on low spec and the resolution is set at 1366x768

I have Directx11 and I updated my video driver to the most current one (released 5/9/11) and the graphics are still no good.

If anyone can help please let me know

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22396

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum requirements of The Witcher 2 for the graphics card are an Nvidia GF 8800GT or an equivalent AMD graphics card. Your Radeon HD 5450 is an HTPC card, not a graphics card meant for playing games. It has about 1/4 of the performance of the minimum requirement ([see this test in german, compare it with the 9800 GT](http://www.computerbase.de/artikel/grafikkarten/2010/test-sapphire-radeon-hd-5450/12/#abschnitt_performancerating)).

I'm sorry, but you're below the minimum requirements and I don't believe you can get the game to run adequately on your computer without a graphics card change. But everything else in your computer seems fine for the game, so you would only need to put in a new mid-range graphics card.

Comment: would a PNY - GeForce GT 440 1GB GDDR5 PCI Express Graphics Card
be a suitable card?

Comment: I would try to go for something a bit better like a ati 5770.

Comment: @Rob_IGS I don't think it will be enough. I would suggest you to buy at least and ATI 6850/6870 or nVidia GTX 460 / 550 Ti.