# Why is my Call Of Duty Black Ops 2 not loading?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I'm having a problem: Call Of Duty Black Ops 2 is not opening at all, not even bringing a window and saying not responding, it's just not loading. How can I fix this?

My system specifications:

- Graphics Card: Intel HD graphics
- Processor: Intel Core i3 m370 (4 cores)
- OS: Windows 7
- RAM: 6GB

Comment: You can't have 6GB of ram?! I thought ram was FLASH memory

Comment: @Alex, you can have 6 GB of RAM as 3 lots of 2 or a 4 and a 2. regardless, it is entirely possible that asker has been told they have 6GB by their system, in context of having 8 total with 2 being used already by the OS.

Comment: Reopening as per [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11736/how-should-we-handle-why-doesnt-this-game-run-questions-when-the-askers-post?cb=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your PC specifications as listed do not meet Black Ops II's minimum required specifications. At a minimum, you need:

---

- **OS:** Windows Vista SP2 / Windows 7 (Windows XP is unsupported)
- **Processor:**

  - Intel Core2 Duo E8200 2.66 GHz
  - or AMD Phenom X3 8750 2.4 GHz
  - or better
- **Memory:**

  - **32-bit OS:** 2GB RAM
  - **64-bit OS:** 4GB RAM
- **Graphics:**

  - NVIDIA GeForce 8800GT 512 MB
  - or ATI Radeon HD 3870 512 MB
  - or better

<sub>From [System Requirements Lab](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/call-of-duty-black-o/11439)</sub>

---

It would seem your Graphics Card (Intel HD Graphics) is the bottleneck here. 'Intel HD Graphics' is usually a fallback graphics processor, meant to display desktop applications in the event that another, more powerful graphics processor is not available.

If you are playing on a notebook or laptop (more than likely, given your processor is the **m**370 line), your laptop may come with a better processor inbuilt which you may will need to select or force Black Ops II to run on. How to do this differs from laptop to laptop, but here's a [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCh9Eob0mNY) that shows the process and can give you a general overview.

In future, if a game is not running at all, you should first check if your PC is [powerful enough to run a game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/517/how-can-i-check-if-my-computers-powerful-enough-to-run-a-certain-game), there are many tools out there that can help you this. From the answer on the above linked question, the ['Can You Run It?'](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri) tool is a very good source of this information.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have any dedicated Graphics you cannot run Black ops 3 easily unless you decrease your graphics quality and resolution.

But it should at least start.

So the problem is not with the system but with the installed game.

SO if possible install the game again and if it does not start look for a file in the game folder which has the graphic settings pre-listed and change them so that game can run on your system.