# Can I run a Minecraft server and play on the same computer? (with my specs, 15+ players)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I want to run a Minecraft server and play on that server using the same machine, with maybe 15-20 or so friends playing on the server. I've seen other people ask this question before, but they stated that there would only be like 5-10 people on the server. My knowledge is that the more players, the more RAM and resource intensive the server is. I've provided my PC specs below. I'm wondering if my PC is powerful enough to run the server on it with everyone playing and still get decent fps (like 50+). Or if I should get a dedicated PC to run the server. Thanks in advance :-)

My Specs:

i7 6700k - OC to 4.5GHz (4c/8t)

24GB DDR4 RAM

50 - 75Mbps  (Up) 10Mbps (Down) Internet Connection

MSi r7 370 Graphics

64GB SSD

2TB HDD

Windows 8.1 Pro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if my computer's powerful enough to run a certain game?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/517/how-can-i-check-if-my-computers-powerful-enough-to-run-a-certain-game)

Comment: @galacticninja the info he is searching won't be available on the site your link's post's answer.

Comment: Also minecraft is not coded well. its not properly optimised, so you need perrty beefy specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think that your computer is powerful enough to run it all.
But keep in mind that the RAM is not the only thing that is important when you are thinking about creating servers.

The processor is also important to estimate the max player count your computer can stand.