# Can Elite Dangerous run old old GPUs?

Tags: elite-dangerous, performance, graphics-card

I'd like to buy Elite:Dangerous, the Steam minimum requirements say "Nvidia GTX 470 / AMD R/ 240" and "DirectX: Version 11"
I have an Nvidia GT 730. My friend says I should be able to run it, but I am not sure.
Can I smoothly run the game with my GPU?

Comment: For your information, the GTX 470 (2010) is actually quite a bit older than the GT 730 (2014). However, the 470 is a high-end card, while the 730 is low-end.

Comment: I feel this question is essentially answer by [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/517/how-can-i-check-if-my-computers-powerful-enough-to-run-a-certain-game).

Comment: Ok, thankyou. I think I should be able to run it

Comment: @TimmyJim Windows Experience AND a Java applet in the same answer? Ooooooof LOL

Comment: Run versus _run it nicely_ are two different things mind you. It'll likely run, but it might not be the greatest experience.

Comment: @nightsurfer the applet I think still holds true, but Windows Experience is certainly not a good way to tell in my opinion (do modern Windows OSes have this even???). I doubt that was even really a good way to tell back in the day.