# Can I play CS2 with 4 GB of RAM?

Tags: system-requirements, counter-strike-2

After *CS2* was released, I quickly downloaded it. Then I tried to open it, but it wouldn't open. I tried to run as an admin, disable fullscreen optimization, and clear my old launch options. But it still can't open.

I meet all the minimum requirements except for the RAM. My RAM is 4 GB.

I wonder if there is any way to run *CS2* with 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: I doubt it. If the devs say you need at least 8 GB RAM for the game, then you can't play it with any less than that. At best, you'd have to mod the game to reduce texture size and whatnot, but this being a multiplayer game, you're risking getting banned for doing so.

Comment: 8Gb of RAM is low by todays standards.  4Gb is extremely low.  You'll be hard pressed to play any games these days with that amount unfortunately.

Comment: If you run Windows 10 you definitely can't. Or do you have another OS installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if my computer's powerful enough to run a certain game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/517/how-can-i-check-if-my-computers-powerful-enough-to-run-a-certain-game)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended requirement for CS2 is 16 GB RAM, while 8 being the minimum but still CS2 can be run over 4GB RAM, you might face issues like lower frame rates (fps) for it will take more time for your RAM to render frames and CPU heating, though you'll need to have minimum background processes running for better optimization. You can check better at this website by uploading your PC specs: [Check Here](https://www.pcgamebenchmark.com/input/counter-strike-2)

You have not mentioned your CPU processor and Graphic card specs, a higher processor and Graphic card can highly assist in compensating the lack of RAM.

Well here I don't think the issue is with the RAM and as well a lot of other factors like GPU, Proper Cooling, etc should also be considered, My personal recommendation would be to try reinstalling the game and also getting an RAM upgrade for 4GB is too less for the software and games of this era.